# Sharing home media on the web

Tags: streaming, media-manager, home-server

What are leading solutions today for sharing **on the Internet**, via a **web interface**, **photos** and/or **videos** (streaming) and other resources from a **home server**?

- Prefer minimum firewall intervention (homeside).
- Prefer unique domains and IPs (For clients behind company firewalls).
- Should work well for clients inside home network - pulling heavy resources locally.
- Flexible sharing possibilities.

I would like to hear about solutions that are god for only videos, or only photos clips.
I think now discontinued [orb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orb_(software)#What_it_does) and *Opera Unite* could have been a good solutions (for streaming media).

Comment: I posted tonido as an answer, but it was deleted.

Comment: Are you looking for a free solution?  Or, are you willing to spend some money?

Answer (score 2):

I believe using Google Drives sharing technology will more than fit your needs. You can make folders and share numerous properties of said folder to other people. They don't even need a Google Profile but it is suggested.

Comment: I think the OP's point is not to have to upload his whole hard drives upfront.

Comment: What are you talking about Franck? I didn't say anything about backing up whole hard drives. Maybe you are not familiar with google drive. My intentions were uploading individual files.

Comment: I am not looking for a cloud solution. (Though you might call it "private cloud" - Tonido uses that term).  This is because of the size of the data and also home LAN clients.  The Internet web client interface of clouds are "good" though.

Comment: What about shutterfly for photos?

Comment: Isnt that just another photo sharing site.

Answer (score 1):

If you thought Tonido might be an answer, then you should look at [OwnCloud](http://owncloud.org/).

This enables you to host your files locally or in a storage cloud and grant permission to users to access them from your home network or outside.

I believe it covers all your stated requirements.

Comment: Btw, you can use [Bitnami's installers for owncloud](https://bitnami.com/stack/owncloud) for easy installation.